# What is the most likely to succeed way to detect attached disks in FreeBSD?

Tags: hard-drive, freebsd

I have seen at least 3 different ways to view attached disks in FreeBSD. Is one more likely to succeed in detecting disks than the others? Here are the three that I know about:

```
camcontrol devlist

geom disk list

sysctl kern.disks
```

and a 4th seemingly more passive approach that doesn't seem ideal:

```
dmesg
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to solve a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can `cat /var/run/devd.pipe` to listen of various device related events. These include creating of `disk` GEOM's, so you don't have to poll `geom disk list` command.